# How to scrape address information from Google Maps?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a macro that pulls a list of addresses from Excel and inputs each one into Google Maps.

It then pulls the address line, city/zip and country from Google Maps back into Excel.

It works up to the point where it scrapes the information from Google Maps.

```
Sub AddressLookup() 

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 1 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim itemELE As Object
    Dim address As String
    Dim city As String
    Dim country As String

    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://www.google.com/maps"

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Dim Search As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set Search = IE.document

    Search.all.q.Value = Cells(i, 1).Value

    Dim ele As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim eles As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

    Set eles = Search.getElementsByTagName("button")

    For Each ele In eles

            If ele.ID = "searchbox-searchbutton" Then
                ele.click
        Else
        End If

    Next ele

    For Each itemELE In IE.document.getElementsByClassName("widget-pane widget-pane-visible")
        address = itemELE.getElementsByClassName("section-hero-header-description")(0).getElementsByTagName("h1")(0).innerText
        city = itemELE.getElementsByClassName("section-hero-header-description")(0).getElementsByTagName("h2")(0).innerText
        country = itemELE.getElementsByClassName("section-hero-header-description")(0).getElementsByTagName("h2")(1).innerText

    Next

    Cells(i, 2).Value = Trim(address)
    Cells(i, 3).Value = Trim(city)
    Cells(i, 4).Value = Trim(country)

    MsgBox country

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe use Google's Map API instead?

Comment: Definitly use Google's [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro), instead of slow and unreliable (ugly) scrapeing

Comment: I've never used an API before so I wouldn't even know where to start

Comment: See my link above to start, but I have noticed that they changed their Terms of Use. Not sure what is free now. You can use [VBA-Web](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web) to send request and parse the reponse. As free alternative (but respect the [Usage Policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/)), you can use [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Examples) Open Street Map. For heavy usage install your own OSM. Maybe I create an VBA-Web example dor that as answer later.

Comment: you should provide test input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

The geocoding API is no longer "free" though I actually believe with a billing account set-up you can scrape for free if you remain within a certain threshold. As a new release (maps/APIs has been updated) I think the expectation is that these APIs are used in conjunction with actual maps (but don't quote me on that).

Please note the following:

1) Use a proper wait for page load **and** after `.click`

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

2) Use `.Navigate2` rather than `.Navigate`

3) Use ids as faster for selections. They generally are unique so no looping required

4) In this case additional time is needed to allow for url to update and map to zoom etc.  I have added a timed loop for this. I show a single example as it is clear you know how to loop.

```
Option Explicit    
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, arr() As String, address As String, city As String, country As String
    Dim addressElement As Object, t As Date, result As String
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10              '<==adjust time here
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.google.com/maps"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .querySelector("#searchboxinput").Value = "united nations headquarters,USA"
            .querySelector("#searchbox-searchbutton").Click
        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        t = Timer
        Do
            DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
            Set addressElement = .document.querySelector(".section-info-line span.widget-pane-link")
            result = addressElement.innerText
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            On Error GoTo 0
        Loop While addressElement Is Nothing
        If InStr(result, ",") > 0 Then
            arr = Split(result, ",")
            address = arr(0)
            city = arr(1)
            country = arr(2)

            With ActiveSheet
                .Cells(1, 2).Value = Trim$(address)
                .Cells(1, 3).Value = Trim$(city)
                .Cells(1, 4).Value = Trim$(country)
            End With
        End If
        Debug.Print .document.URL
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

In terms of selectors -

Commercial addresses:

```
.section-info-line span.widget-pane-link
```

And feedback from OP re: residential:

```
.section-hero-header div.section-hero-header-description
```

Comment: @SIM  Thanks. I still think it can be improved. I have tried to use a selector I think will hold but I haven’t used a lot of test cases to be honest.

Comment: You can pass the query in URL and skip "insert query" and "click". See [guide#search-action](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#search-action)

Comment: @ComputerVersteher yup I believe so.

Comment: Thank you! this is great! i can't seem to get it to work when it actually takes a value from the spreadsheet though. For example, if I pull value A1 (i.e value is 21 Bay St Toronto) it won't fully load and therefore won't pull the value into the spreadsheet. Any ideas?
EXAMPLE: 
 .querySelector("#searchboxinput").Value = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value

Comment: Hi, I will have a go today/tomorrow with that value.

Comment: Hey, I actually figured it out mostly - looks like not all addresses will work with using the ".section-info-line span.widget-pane-link" so I had to use ".section-hero-header div.section-hero-header-description". commercial addresses seem to work with your version but not regular street addresses (which is what I'm trying to find)

Comment: that's ok. It's really the structure that is key. Selectors are easy to tweak. I'll update answer. I only worked with an address I had.

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses the [OpenStreetMap Nominatim API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) with the [VBA-Web](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web) WebRequest.

In opposite to scraping with`Internet Explorer`this is designed for this purpose (faster, more reliable, more information). This can be done with the [Geocode API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) too, but you need an API-Key and keep track of the cost.

If you use  https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search respect their [Usage Policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/), but better have your own installation.

```
Public Function GeocodeRequestNominatim(ByVal sAddress As String) As Dictionary
    Dim Client As New WebClient
    Client.BaseUrl = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/"

    Dim Request As New WebRequest
    Dim Response As WebResponse
    Dim address As Dictionary

    With Request
        .Resource = "search/"
        .AddQuerystringParam "q", sAddress
        .AddQuerystringParam "format", "json"
        .AddQuerystringParam "polygon", "1"
        .AddQuerystringParam "addressdetails", "1"
    End With
    Set Response = Client.Execute(Request)
    If Response.StatusCode = WebStatusCode.Ok Then
       Set address = Response.Data(1)("address")
       Set GeocodeRequestNominatim = address

       'Dim Part As Variant
       'For Each Part In address.Items
       '    Debug.Print Part
       'Next Part

    Else
      Debug.Print "Error: " & Response.StatusCode & " - " & Response.Content
    End If
End Function
```

Example (prints country, for other fields have a look at the returned JSON-String in example on Nomination Website):

```
Debug.Print GeocodeRequestNominatim("united nations headquarters,USA")("country")
```

Answer (score 0):

After running your code and inspecting Google's address search result, I was able to retrieve the entire address block 'City, Province Postal_Code' by referencing the span tag inside the section-hero-header-subtitle class.

Without making any other changes to your code, add the following line above your For-Each loop (that loops through widget-pane widget-pane visible class) and step thru the code using F8.

```
Debug.Print IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("section-hero-header-subtitle")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
```

Comment: I for some reason still cannot get it to work - did you change anything else?